typescript-language-server "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import"
I'm trying to get the typescript language server running.
I'm running node version 8.15.1
The command "npm install -g typescript-language-server typescript" installed the module without error.
After installation, I run this command: typescript-language-server
This results in the following output:
home/bob/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/typescript-language-server/lib/cli.mjs:2
import fs$l, { promises, statSync, existsSync, readFileSync as readFileSync$1 } from 'node:fs';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
❯ typescript-language-server
/home/bob/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/typescript-language-server/lib/cli.mjs:2
import fs$l, { promises, statSync, existsSync, readFileSync as readFileSync$1 } from 'node:fs';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3


